# How to get the first n rows of a csv file with a specific column value?

Tags: bash, awk, grep, cut

In Kaggle, I have got a csv file like this:

```
ip,app,device,os,channel,click_time,attributed_time,is_attributed
83230,3,1,13,379,2017-11-06 14:32:21,,0
17357,3,1,19,379,2017-11-06 14:33:34,,1
35810,3,1,13,379,2017-11-06 14:34:12,,0
45745,14,1,13,478,2017-11-06 14:34:52,,0
161007,3,1,13,379,2017-11-06 14:35:08,,1
18787,3,1,16,379,2017-11-06 14:36:26,,0
103022,3,1,23,379,2017-11-06 14:37:44,,0
114221,3,1,19,379,2017-11-06 14:37:59,,0
```

Now I want to fetch the first 200 rows whose "is_attributed" is 1. How I can do that with "cut" and other utilities please?

Comment: while asking question, please also add what you've tried yourself to solve this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the columns don't change, you can use a simple regexp match:

```
grep -E  '(^ip,|,1$)' »file.csv« | head -n 201
```

Comment: with GNU grep, you could do `grep -m201 -E  '(^ip,|,1$)'`

Answer (score 4):

With `awk` you can do the filtering as well as line limiting in one go:

```
awk -F, -v limit=200 '$NF == 1 { if (++n > limit) exit; print }' file.csv
```

- `-F,`                   - the delimiter is a comma
- `-v limit=200`          - initializes the variable to be used inside awk command
- `$NF == 1`              - take action only if the last field has a value of 1
- `if (++n > limit) exit` - stop reading the input as soon as we collect the desired number of lines

We are implicitly skipping the header line in the above solution, since the header doesn't end with a 1.  To be more robust, we can make it explicit:

```
awk -F, -v limit=200 'NR  == 1 { next }
                      $NF == 1 { if (++n > limit) exit; print }' file.csv
```

---

This is a better solution than `grep ... | head -n` because of a few reasons:

- no pipeline (and an extra fork) involved here
- we stop as soon as we reach the line limit; this can make a huge difference if the input file is very large (`grep -m` can do this as well)
- it is very easy to extend this solution to an arbitrary field, not just the first or the last one
- if the delimiter is multi-character one or it needs to be matched by a regex, then awk handles it very easily

---

Related post:

- [Using grep vs awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/88503/201820) on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange

Comment: `grep ... | head -n` will also stop when you reach the line limit because head will close the pipe and so cause a terminate signal (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGPIPE) to be returned to grep when the limit is reached.

Answer (score 0):

To get all lines that match the criteria, pipe through `grep ,1$ | head -n 200`.